# cakePHP : password is not hashing while adding user

Tags: cakephp, hash, cakephp-2.7

I'm using **cakephp 2.7.8** for building an admin panel. My project contains multiple admin instead of users that's why I have `admins` table in database and not users.
using BlowfishHasher for hashing of password, but while creating new record(adding new user) the password is not hashing and simply string is being stored to password table.

**Query for table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `admins` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

**Admins model : Admin.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher','Controller/Component/Auth');
/**
 * Admin Model
 *
 */
class Admin extends AppModel {

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */

    public $displayField = 'first_name';


        public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
            if(isset($this->data[$this->alias['password']])){
                $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
                $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
                    $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
                        );
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

**Admins Controller : AdminsController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Admins Controller
 *
 * @property Admin $Admin
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 * @property FlashComponent $Flash
 * @property SessionComponent $Session
 */
class AdminsController extends AppController {

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator', 'Flash', 'Session');

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Admin->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('admins', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
/**
 * login function
 */
        public function login(){
            if($this->request->is('post')) {
                if($this->Auth->login()) {
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                }
                $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }

/**
 * logout function
 */
        public function logout(){
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
        }
}
```

**App Controller : AppController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

/**
 * @package     app.Controller
 * @link        http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller
 */
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Flash',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect'=>array(
                'controller'=>'admins',
                'action'=>'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect'=>array(
                'controller'=>'admins',
                'action'=>'login'
            ),
            'authenticate'=>array(
                'Form'=>array(
                    'passwordHasher'=>'Blowfish'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
            AuthComponent::ALL => array(
                'userModel' => 'Admin'
            )
        );
        $this->Auth->allow('login','add','index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error on this line:-

```
if(isset($this->data[$this->alias['password']])){
```

It should be:-

```
if(isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])){
```

Comment: thanks it worked, i was searching for the error from yesterday. anyway but now login is not working. It is saying username password incorrect